# Gui library for game

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl

I'm making a game with OpenGL render api. Now I need in level editor. It should consist of lots of widgets parents/children etc, so it's hard to write need widgets by hands.
Any ideas about good gui-system which can be easilly connected with opengl? The most important part is gui editing. I really need some editing-tool for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have a look to http://qt.nokia.com/ .

It is very easy to inject the OpenGL rendering into Qt widgets.

To easily edit your GUI, you can use Qt Creator ( http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools ).

Answer (score 1):

Check out CEGUI:

http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

It defines its GUIs in XML and has editors for it.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options (and this has been answered before, but probably not exactly like this):

1. SDL: very good abstraction layer for audio, graphics and anything related. It will force you to write your widget stuff by hand.
2. Qt: has an OpenGL module that makes it easy to set up an OpenGL context. It will make widgets and everything very easy.
3. wxWidgets: same as Qt, but has slightly worse documentation and tools (if I might be so blunt)

I'd go with number two: it has a beautiful Designer tool to create Widgets with all the fancyness you'll need. OpenGL is also built right in.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Windows (can't confirm Mono will do it), another option would be to use C# and WinForms to make your life significantly easier.